# How to use Crow on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, webserver, ifttt

I'm trying to start a webserver using a Raspberry Pi for listening to POST requests from IFTTT. I'm programming in C++. I first tried Crow, which wouldn't work at all, giving the error "Handler function cannot have void return type...". I saw that others had also had issues with it, so I looked for a new solution. I found RestINIO, which looks great, but I can't figure out how to install it on my Raspberry PI. I looked at the docs, but couldn't figure out how to get it to install.

I know this probably isn't the right place for this, but any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Well I managed to get both (Crow and Restinio) installed and working not long ago... Concerning the Crow error message, that seems like a pretty obvious error from your side. Can you speficy in more detail, what you tried, and which error messages you got while installing Restinio?

Comment: @JakobStark Here's what happens when I try to use Crow, I may be making an obvious error though:

I first go to https://github.com/CrowCpp/Crow/releases/tag/v1.0+4 and download the deb file to try to install it that way. When running it on my Raspberry Pi, it gives me the error `dpkg: error processing archive, package architecture (amd64) does not match system (armhf)`. Makes sense, my system is powered by a different architecture.

I then try to download/include crow_all.h with `#include "crow_all.h"` at the top of my .cpp file. Here's the error I get: https://pastebin.com/gZnffjfw

Comment: Never mind, got it fixed. Had to include "-lboost_system" in geany, will post here as solution. Thanks for replying though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I had to do (simple fix):

In Geany:

Go to Build > Set Build Commands

Under both "compile" and "build", add the following text to the end of the string: `-lboost_system`

Compilation is successful!

Comment: That is **not** the answer for your original question though. Consider changing the question to something like "How to use Crow on a raspberry pi?" That way others with the same problem will more likely find this answer.